# Video player for GNU Linux

Tags: linux, video, ubuntu

I'm looking for a video player which runs on GNU Linux (Ubuntu 16.04, most importantly) and fulfills these criteria:

- Can play several videos at once.
- Does not misbehave if the file it's playing gets deleted / moved. So it should not stop playing the video (I'm not aware of any video player which does this.), suddenly have 100% CPU load (VLC does this.), nor do anything else stupid. It should just continue playing the video (like MPV does).
- Can play videos full-screen.
- It's possible to skip in intervals of a few seconds. I don't care by which means (scroll wheel, arrow keys, other keys), just not via on-screen buttons, and I don't care whether it's 3 s, 5, s, or 10 s, just not like 30 s or 10% of the video or 1 frame at a time.
- Can play videos at 1.5 times normal speed.

MPV satisfies all but the last criterion, but I don't know of any video player which satisfies all of them.

Ideally, it should close itself once the video its playing finished, but this is optional.

Comment: You would need to buffer the entire file into RAM before playing if you want to avoid hiccups when the file being played is deleted mid-play

Comment: @ivanivan That's just not true. You only delete the directory entry. The ref counter doesn't drop to zero if an application holds a file descriptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to figure out whether and as the case may be how to increase the playback speed of MPV for years, now, and never found anything when googling for it.

Luckily, when I wrote this question, I complained about MPV elsewhere and got a reply saying that you can modify the playback speed using curly braces and box brackets. This turned out to be true. Therefore: Problem solved as MPV satisfies all necessary requirements. It also satisfies the nice-to-have feature! :)